# Some data of Firebase databse is not displayed in recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have created an app and stored some data in firebase database. I want to show the data in recyclerview but all the data is not populated i.e. Data of 4 fields is displaying but data of two fields (bloodgroup and phone no) is not displayed by the recyclerview. Below is my code. Thanks in advance

**My Adapter** RcvAdapter

```
public class RcvAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelClass, RcvAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    public RcvAdapter(@NonNull @NotNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelClass> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull @NotNull ModelClass model) {

        holder.uAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
        holder.uBGroup.setText(model.getBloodGroup());
        holder.uCity.setText(model.getCity());
        holder.uDistrict.setText(model.getDistrict());
        holder.uName.setText(model.getName());
        holder.uPhone.setText(model.getPhoneNumber());
        holder.uContact.setText(model.getContact());
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dashboard_rcv_layout, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView uAddress;
        TextView uBGroup;
        TextView uCity;
        TextView uDistrict;
        TextView uName;
        TextView uPhone;
        TextView uContact;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            uAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcv_address);
            uBGroup =(TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcv_bloodGroup);
            uCity =(TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcv_city);
            uDistrict =(TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcv_district);
            uName =(TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcv_name);
            uPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcv_phoneNumber);
            uContact =(TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.rcv_contact);
        }
    }
```

**Recyclerview single row layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_address"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:text="Lal colony"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rcv_phoneNumber"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rcv_phoneNumber"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rcv_phoneNumber" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_district"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:text="Malakand"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rcv_city"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rcv_city"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rcv_city" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_city"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:text="Thana"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rcv_address"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rcv_address"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rcv_address" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Address"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="City"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="District"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_bloodGroup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:text="Blood Group"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rcv_name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rcv_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rcv_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_phoneNumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
            android:text="+923005658587"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rcv_name"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rcv_bloodGroup" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rcv_contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="Contact"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#2196F3"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="250dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Blood Group"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Phone No"
            android:textColor="#070707"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**My MainActivity**

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RcvAdapter adapter;
   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);




        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
       
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
  //      database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

// Retrive firebase data into recyclerview
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ModelClass> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelClass>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users"), ModelClass.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new RcvAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

            adapter.stopListening();

    }
```

**ModelClass**

```
public class ModelClass {

    String address;
    String bloodGroup;
    String city;
    String district;
    String name;
    String phoneNumber;
    String contact;

    public ModelClass() {

    }

    public ModelClass(String address, String bloodGroup, String city, String district, String name, String phoneNumber, String contact) {
        this.address = address;
        this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
        this.city = city;
        this.district = district;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getBloodGroup() {
        return bloodGroup;
    }

    public void setBloodGroup(String bloodGroup) {
        this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
    
}
```

data of blood group and Phone No is no populating.

[image: This is snapshot of my firebase database]

**DashboardActivity Layout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_red"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: At first glance the code looks fine and matches the data structure, but it's hard to debug it on sight along. I recommend setting breakpoints in `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` and running in a debugger to see if they ever get called. If not, that means that no data is being returned from the database, and I'd recommend checking the logcat output for errors.

Comment: It might be that the view is being clipped (squished between the other fields). I notice that @id/rcv_contact has a `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` while all the other ones have a `android:layout_width="0dp"`. is this intentional? Also, general advice, I'd recommend making sure the view builds correctly with dummy data (take out the firebase piece and create a mock model) to make sure the view/adapter work independent of the firebase piece.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen there are no errors in the logcat.

Comment: @sleepystar96 yes these are intentional, I have even used linearlayout but data of only two fields is not populating while data of 4 fields is populating.

Comment: Does `model.getAddress()` return inside `onBindViewHolder`, the correct data?

Comment: @Zeeshankhan ok, thanks for letting me know you ruled out a view problem! I see something new: how are you decoding the data from firebase to the `ModelClass` class? Do you have a custom decoder or are you using the default functionality of FirebaseRecyclerOptions? If it's the latter, then I would assume that the variable names must match between your database and the class for auto decoding. Try changing "phoneNumber" in `ModelClass` to "phone" (same as database) and see if that helps?

Comment: @sleepystar96 problem solved. Matching the variables names of model class with firebasedatabse solved it. Please post it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the default encoder/decoder with the FirebaseRecycler class, you should make sure to match the key names in the database with the key names in your model.

For example,  Try changing "phoneNumber" in `ModelClass` to "phone" (same as database).